# How can I using islice, slice an exact number of records from a fasta file

Tags: python, python-itertools, biopython

I am using the following code to alter the fasta names from a fasta file of DNA sequences.  I set the number of sequences to the full number of sequences in the original fasta file but the output is always less.  In other words if my original fasta file contained 50 sequences, the resulting fasta file with altered names would only have 49 despite me setting the number of sequences to slice to 50.  With 100 sequences in the original file, the resulting file ends up with only 98.  What am I missing.

```
from itertools import islice

infile = mydatadirpath + "ExportFastaFile.fasta"

records = SeqIO.parse(infile, "fasta")

FileToExportShortNamesTo = mydatadirpath + "ExportShortNamesFastaFile.fasta"


g = open(FileToExportShortNamesTo,"w+")

randnumseqs = 50

counter = 0

for record in islice(records, randnumseqs):
    Name = record.description
    counter = counter + 1
    Namer = ">" + str(Name)[0:1] + str(counter)
    seqstring = str(record.seq)
    
    g.write(Namer + "\n" + seqstring + "\n")
```

I have tried increasing the number of sequences to slice by 1 thinking it might be an indexing issue but that changes nothing.  What am I doing wrong?

Example Input would be like the following but with 50 records instead of the 10 shown here:

```
>EAAA1
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTGTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
>EAAA2
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTTTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
>EAAA3
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTTTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
>EAAA4
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTTTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
>EAAA5
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTTTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
>EAAA6
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTTTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
>EAAA7
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTTTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
>EAAA8
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTTTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
>EAAAE9
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTTTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
>EAAA10
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTTTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
```

And the output should look like but again with 50 records instead of the 10 shown:

```
>E1
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTGTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
>E2
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTTTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
>E3
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTTTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
>E4
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTTTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
>E5
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTTTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
>E6
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTTTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
>E7
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTTTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
>E8
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTTTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
>E9
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTTTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
>E10
AGCAGGAGCAACGTACCCTTACCAATTTAGTACGTATTCTTTTACTACTTGAGTTGTTTAATCATTCCTTCCT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching this `Namer = ">" + str(Name)[0:1] + str(counter)` to `Namer = ">" + str(Name)[:1] + str(counter)`

That `0` is making it such that it always starts after the first element

Comment: I tried that but it did not change anything.  I still just get 49 records.  That 0 is just telling it to parse out the second character of the name of each record.  It doesn't effect what record it is working on.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The file that I was using as input was created using code in a previous cell.  I did not close that file after it was created so there was no EOF and the code that I posted was therefore not reading the final record.  I closed the file between the two blocks of code and there it was 50 records, problem solved.